# Read all images from subfolder, resize them and save them with their original name in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to read all images from a different subfolder, resize them and save them with their original name. However, I get the error shown below. How do I fix this error?

example code:

```
from PIL import Image

import os

size = (112, 112)

def resize_img(path,dest_path):

    name_list = []
    label_list = []
    resized_list = []
    if not os.path.exists(dest_path):
        os.makedirs(dest_path)
    folder_list = os.listdir(path)
    for num_imgs,folder in enumerate(folder_list):
        print(str(num_imgs) + " : " + folder)
        files_path = path + "/" + folder
        image_list = os.listdir(files_path)
        name_list.append(folder)
        for image_name in image_list:
            image_path = path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_name
            print(image_path)
            img = Image.open(image_path)
            label_list.append(img)
            for image in label_list:
                image = image.resize((112, 112))
                resized_list.append(image)
                for (i,new) in enumerate (resized_list):
                    new.save('{}{}{}'.format(dest_path+'/'+str(label_list)+str('_'), i+1, '.jpg'))

resize_img('C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/Face_database',
           'C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/resized_images')
```

Error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/smaple2.py", line 30, in <module>
    'C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/resized_images')

  File "C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/smaple2.py", line 27, in resize_img
    new.save('{}{}{}'.format(dest_path+'/'+str(label_list)+str('_'), i+1, '.jpg'))

  File "C:\Users\aunglay\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2099, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/resized_images/[<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=64x64 at 0x2D7ACFD508>]_1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the last line of the code:

```
new.save('{}{}{}'.format(dest_path+'/'+str(label_list)+str('_'), i+1, '.jpg'))
```

Specifically, label_list will be a list of image objects and will not contain the name of the image you just read. Plus, I think the last two for loops are not necessary. You could change the code:

```
for image_name in image_list:
        image_path = path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_name
        print(image_path)
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        label_list.append(img)
        for image in label_list:
            image = image.resize((112, 112))
            resized_list.append(image)
            for (i,new) in enumerate (resized_list):
                new.save('{}{}{}'.format(dest_path+'/'+str(label_list)+str('_'), i+1, '.jpg'))
```

to:

```
for image_name in image_list:
        image_path = path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_name
        print(image_path)
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        label_list.append(img)
        resized_list.append(img.resize((112, 112)))
        resized_list[-1].save(dest_path+'/'+image_name+'.jpg')
```

And that should implement what you describe.

edit:
concerning what was asked in the comments:

```
def resize_img(path,dest_path):

   name_list = []
   label_list = []
   resized_list = []
   folder_list = os.listdir(path)
   for num_imgs,folder in enumerate(folder_list):
       if not os.path.exists(dest_path+'/'+folder):
           os.makedir(dest_path+'/'+folder)
       print(str(num_imgs) + " : " + folder)
       files_path = path + "/" + folder
       image_list = os.listdir(files_path)
       name_list.append(folder)
       for image_name in image_list:
          image_path = path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_name
          print(image_path)
          img = Image.open(image_path)
          label_list.append(img)
          resized_list.append(img.resize((112, 112)))
          resized_list[-1].save(dest_path+'/'+folder+'/'+image_name+'.jpg'
```

This should implement what you were describing. You need to call os.mkdir() for each of the sub-folders you want to create, thus it has to be inside the first for loop.

Comment: Thanks to you. It's work. But all resized images will be save only in one folder, no more subfolder. How can i fix this: in face_database  folder had 5 subfolder with their name but after resized images, them saved in only one folder. And i want to ask to you what for [-1] in  "resized_list[-1]"? please.

Comment: The resized_list[-1] means the last element in resized_list. Concerning the file folders, do you want to save each set of image in a different sub-folder, each named after the folder from where the image was read?

Comment: Yes,of course. In code : image_path = path + "/" + folder + "/" + image_name,
path = 'C:/Users/aunglay/PycharmProjects/FR_using_cnn/Face_database'.
In  this folder "Face_database" had 5 different sub_folder.I want to read each images from different sub_folder and want to resize, and then want to save resized images with their original name to each sub_folder where the image was read, please. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could create sub-folders with the same name in the destination by adding os.mkdir(dest_path+''/"+folder) before the last for loop, then replacing the last line with resized_list[-1].save(dest_path+'/'+folder+'/'+image_name+'.jpg')

Comment: show me example please. I did try but not work and error occurred. How can i add os.mkdir before the last for loop? please

Comment: I did add this comment before the last "for loop" 
       for folders in folder_list:
            file_name = dest_path+ '/'+ folders
            if not os.path.exists(file_name):
                os.mkdir(file_name)
resized_list[-1].save(dest_path+'/'+folder+'/'+image_name+'.jpg')
It was made 5 sub_folder in dest_path, but resized images didn't save in their folder and error appeared. I want to resize images and save them in their  sub folder. please help me.